# JS this, that and .then mindF@#$ed

Tags: javascript, class, selenium-webdriver, es6-promise

Feeling supper rusty;

I have a couple promises that still need to access a previous this in a class, I am trying to do this the most elegant way possible. I am using webdriverJS here should explain all the driver... Thanks for your help!

```
class funManeger 
async fillOutDForm ( ){
try{
    let that = this;
    await driver.findElement( this.elementKeys.D ).clear();
    await driver.findElement( this.elementKeys.D ).sendKeys(this.search.D);
    await driver.wait(
        webdriver.until.elementLocated(
            this.elementKeys.DDropDown
        ),2250, // timeOut
        'Could not find item in DropDown Item' //error message on timeout
    ).then( async function ( this ){
        try {
            await driver.sleep( this.getRandomInt(7) * 100 );
            await driver.findElement( this.elementKeys.DDropDown ).click();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log( 'error clicking on D DropDown', this.elementKeys.DDropDown, error );
        }
    });

}catch (error){
    console.log('Error Filling out D', error );
}
}
```

Comment: the title is not very descriptive.

Comment: You do not need `.then()` if you are using the `async`/`await` syntax

Comment: I see you have `let that = this;` but I don't spot anywhere in which `that` is used? what are you trying to achieve? where does it break?

Comment: the point of doing `let that = this;` is to save the reference of your `this` situated at `fillOutDForm` level. You should replace all others `this` in your code that refer to your saved value by `that`. The other places where `this` should refer to their own location should be kept as they are.

Comment: If `driver.wait(` is a promise you need the result, just store it.. eg.  `const value = await driver.wait(`

Answer (score 0):

If you are  using `async/await`, you dont need to `.then()`

```
class funManeger {
    async fillOutDForm() {
        try {
            let that = this;
            await driver.findElement(that.elementKeys.D).clear();
            await driver.findElement(that.elementKeys.D).sendKeys(that.search.D);
            let dropdown = await driver.wait(
                webdriver.until.elementLocated(
                    that.elementKeys.DDropDown
                ), 2250, // timeOut
                'Could not find item in DropDown Item' //error message on timeout
            );
            try {
                await driver.sleep(that.getRandomInt(7) * 100);
                await driver.findElement(that.elementKeys.DDropDown).click();
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error clicking on D DropDown', this.elementKeys.DDropDown, error);
            }

        }catch (e) {
            console.log('Error Filling out D', error );
        }
    }
}
```